# Open source alternatives to SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: ssis, open-source

What are some free alternatives to SSIS?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/1449344/359

Comment: Link is not available any more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure if these will meet your needs, but you could take a look at:

1. [Pentaho](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/).
2. [CloverETL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloveretl/).
3. [Talend Open Studio for Data Integration](http://sourceforge.net/projects/talend-studio/).

Or you could do your own additional search at sourceforge.net.

Comment: Hmmm... looks nice. +1 for you!

Comment: I posted those three since they seem to have a lot of tutorials on the net.. I hope one of these will suit your needs (pentaho appears to have the biggest feature set)

Comment: CloverETL is now called CloverDX and there's [no free (community) version](https://www.cloverdx.com/what-happened-to-cloveretl-community-edition) any more.